# MobX: Action-annotated method is undefined

Tags: typescript, annotations, mobx, parceljs

I'm having a strange issue with the MobX annotations, where a method annotated `@action` doesn't exist on the resultant object.

If my class source is the following TypeScript (as a minimal example):

```
export class Car {
    @observable
    public wheels: number = 4;

    @action
    public selfDestruct() {
        this.wheels = 0;
    }
}
```

And I invoke the method as follows:

```
const car = new Car();
car.selfDestruct();
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: car.selfDestruct is not a function
```

Evaluating `car.selfDestruct()` in the console returns `undefined`.

*However*, if I use the action *function* all seems fine:

```
export class Car {
    @observable
    public wheels: number = 4;

    public selfDestruct = action(
        () => this.wheels = 0
    );
}

const car = new Car();

car.selfDestruct(); // works fine
```

For reference, I am using MobX 5.5.2 with TypeScript 3.1.1. The compilation is being handled by ParcelJS 1.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause turned out to be with our tsconfig setup - we had a root config and several child configs, and it seemed the interplay of compiler options between them mangled the output somehow.

Full details of the problem are documented in a MobX GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1790). Our fix was to merely use one unified tsconfig for our entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Does removing `public` from the `selfDestruct` function declaration fix it? I haven't ever used `public` in my actions, so I'm not sure how that will affect the usage of the `@action` decorator.

Comment: Sadly, no. Still the same issue.